# (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor) Error Path:/consumers/consumer1/ids Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm observing following error logs in splunk. Do we need to ignore these error logs or do these logs provide any useful information? I'm also seeing that consumer GET is not receiving the msgs when this message is seen, so looks like these logs provide some useful information. 
Also, this error and issue (consumer GET is not receiving the msgs) is seen only for 1 consumer and not for other.

```
2019-07-29 11:14:04.458 [2019-07-29 11:14:04,457] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x36a8d0dba8501ea type:create cxid:0x3 zxid:0x100046fc6 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers/consumer1/ids Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers/consumer1/ids (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
2019-07-29 11:14:04.458 [2019-07-29 11:14:04,457] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x36a8d0dba8501ea type:create cxid:0x2 zxid:0x100046fc5 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers/consumer1 Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers/consumer1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
```

Comment: Can you share your consumer's configuration?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous Do i need to share the docker-compose file for rest-proxy/broker/zookeeper ?

Comment: That would be useful

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous Have added the docker compose in the query. We are running 3 node kafka cluster, which is load balanced by an ELB. Are these logs providing any useful info ?